# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am a beginner and I am using **Retrofit 2** in my app. I have this **JSON**. (I have tried many solution but nothing worked for me). Thank for your help

**Error which I have**: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

JSON

```
{
   responseCode: 1,
   responseCodeText: "ok",
   response: [
      {
         lat: 67.2422432322,
         lng: 25.1441441441,
         title: "Point na mapě 1",
         desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.\nVero praesentium fugiat nobis pariatur cupiditate saepe dolorum, soluta dignissimos.",
         photo: [
            "http://photo3.jpg",
            "http://photo4.jpg",
         ]
      },
      {
         lat: 39.1234787,
         lng: 25.2242445,
         title: "Point na mapě 2",
         desc: "Possimus veritatis, neque a et odit ad itaque iusto asperiores perspiciatis voluptates,\nvero praesentium fugiat nobis pariatur cupiditate saepe dolorum, soluta dignissimos.",
         photo: [
            "http://photo1.jpg",
            "http://photo2.jpg",
         ]
      }, 
      //other
```

Interface

```
public interface PointsInterface {

        String BASE_URL = "MY_URL/";

         @POST("getPointsOnMap")
         Call<List<PointsOnMap>> getPointsOnMap();

        class Factory {
            private static PointsInterface service;

            public static PointsInterface getInstance() {
                if (service == null) {
                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();
                    service = retrofit.create(PointsInterface.class);
                    return service;
                } else {
                    return service;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

API call

//apiService

```
   public void serviceInit() {
        PointsInterface.Factory.getInstance().getPointsOnMap().enqueue(new Callback<List<PointsOnMap>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<PointsOnMap>> call, Response<List<PointsOnMap>> response) {
                List<PointsOnMap> result = response.body();
                Log.d("response", "Number of points received: " + result.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<PointsOnMap>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", "Error");
            }
        });}
```

Model

```
public class PointsOnMap {

    @SerializedName("lat") private Double lat;
    @SerializedName("lng") private Double lng;
    @SerializedName("title") private String title;
    @SerializedName("desc") private String desc;

    public PointsOnMap(Double lat, Double lng, String title, String desc) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLng() { return lng; }

    public void setLng(Double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Retrofit interface

```
     @POST("getPointsOnMap")
     Call<List<PointsOnMap>> getPointsOnMap();
```

Should be

```
     @POST("getPointsOnMap")
     Call<PointsOnMapResponse> getPointsOnMap();
```

where `PointsOnMapResponse` is

```
public class PointsOnMapResponse {
    @SerializedName("responseCode")
    long responseCode;

    @SerializedName("responseCodeText")
    String responseCodeText;

    @SerializedName("response")
    List<PointsOnMap> response;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to get properties like title, desc, lat and so on from response?

Comment: It would be in the list `response.body().getResponse()`

Answer (score 2):

in PointsInterface replace

```
@POST("getPointsOnMap")
Call<List<PointsOnMap>> getPointsOnMap();
```

> to

```
@POST("getPointsOnMap")
Call<PointsOnMap> getPointsOnMap();
```

> as well as replace

```
 public void serviceInit() {
    PointsInterface.Factory.getInstance().getPointsOnMap().enqueue(new Callback<List<PointsOnMap>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<PointsOnMap>> call, Response<List<PointsOnMap>> response) {
            List<PointsOnMap> result = response.body();
            Log.d("response", "Number of points received: " + result.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<PointsOnMap>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error", "Error");
        }
    });}
```

to

```
 public void serviceInit() {
    PointsInterface.Factory.getInstance().getPointsOnMap().enqueue(new Callback<PointsOnMap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PointsOnMap> call, Response<PointsOnMap> response) {
            PointsOnMap result = response.body();
            Log.d("response", "Number of points received: " + result.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PointsOnMap> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error", "Error");
        }
    });}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the result is null. I added my model class, is it OK? Response from server is OK, so problem is on my side.

Answer (score 2):

this is because of

```
@POST("getPointsOnMap")
Call<List<PointsOnMap>> getPointsOnMap();
```

Here you remove **List** your error will be solved.

```
 @POST("getPointsOnMap")
 Call<PointsOnMap> getPointsOnMap();
```

Good luck